# ASP.NET MVC: Multiple View Folders and _ViewStart.cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewengine

I have an MVC project that requires there to be 2 different View folders. One is at `~/Views/` and one at `~/Framework/Views/`. This is done by creating a custom view engine based on the razor view engine like this:

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private static string[] AdditionalViewLocations = new[]{
        "~/Framework/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Framework/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
        "~/Framework/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Framework/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml"
    };

    public MyViewEngine()            
    {
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
        base.ViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
        base.MasterLocationFormats = base.MasterLocationFormats.Union(AdditionalViewLocations).ToArray();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to use a different _ViewStart.cshtml file in each of the 2 Views folder (i.e. `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` for views found in the `~/Views/` folder and `~/Framework/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` for views found in the `~/Framework/Views/` Folder), however the View Engine just uses the first one it finds which is the original one in `~/Views/`.

Is this possible to do?

Thank you

Comment: Why not use Areas instead of messing with view engine?

Comment: This is definitely possible - in fact I just whipped it up on my machine using the view engine you supplied, just copied and pasted.

I am not seeing the same behavior as you. I have two _ViewStart files, one at ~/Framework/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml, and one at ~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml. When I run a view within ~/Framework/Views/, it uses the Framework _ViewStart. When I run a view within ~/Views/, it uses the _ViewStart there. 

Double checking the code in RazorViewEngine using DotPeek also confirms that this is how it should behave. Are you sure you aren't missing something?

Comment: @NickAceves: Thanks you're right. My file was saved in the wrong location and a duplicate of the wrong file was saved in the right location! What a dooch! Thanks again. (put it in an answer and I'll mark it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is definitely possible, I think you just missed something.

I have tested this myself using the view engine you supplied (copied and pasted verbatim). I am not seeing the same behavior as you. I have two `_ViewStart.cshtml` files, one at `~/Framework/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`, and one at `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`.

When I run a view within `~/Framework/Views/`, it uses the `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the Framework folder. When I run a view within `~/Views/`, it uses the `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the Views folder.

Double checking the code in `RazorViewEngine` using DotPeek also confirms that this is exactly how it should behave. The view engine starts checking in for a file named `_ViewStart.cshtml` within the same folder as the view being rendered, and then walks up the directory tree until it gets to the root of the application.

Answer (score 3):

The selection of `_ViewStart` is hierarchical, but you've added `~/Framework/Views` parallel to `~/Views`. I don't think Razor is set up to actually do what you want (i.e. two completely parallel view locations). If you were to put `Framework` into the main `Views` folder, your `_ViewStart`s would load properly, though.

Comment: I see yes. So would the framework directory be something like this: `~/Views/Framework/_ViewStart.cshtml` and `~/Views/Framework/Controller/Action.cshtml`. And is the custom razor view engine then still needed but changing the AdditionalViewLocations to something like this: `"~/Views/Framework/{1}/{0}.cshtml"`?

Comment: Or is that still parallel view locations? Should I just add the Framework folder as an area? (Haven't used areas before, so sorry if I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: No, that's exactly what I'm talking about. If you put all your "Framework" views together in a folder and put a `_ViewStart` in that folder, then it will apply to everything at that level and below. Think of it as an override. You would no longer need a custom razor engine.

Comment: As for areas, that's a perfectly acceptable approach as well. Areas have their own `Views` folder, but they still look in the main `Views` folder as well. So you could have a "Framework" area, and put a `_ViewStart` in the `~/Areas/Framework/Views` folder.